# Oracle Function based index returning slowly

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have a table setup that contains some 640m records and I'm trying to create an index.

The manner in which I want to select records involves something like this:

```
index_i9(ORA_HASH(placard_bcd,128),event);
```

However that still returns about 3-4 million records, and from my testing, it takes a length amount of time (~12 minutes or so).

Is this a bad idea as an index? I don't think getting 3-4m records should take that long.

Any ideas?

Edit (adding more info):

The table has a bunch of columns but I don't know if I need to list all of them:

```
table_a
container   NOT NULL NUMBER(19),
placard_bcd NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30),
event       NOT NULL VARCHAR(5),
bin_number  NUMBER(3),
...
...
```

It takes about 12 minutes to return all of the records that would return based on the index above. So to provide me all 3-4 million records.

The query used looks something like this:

```
select barcode, event, bin_number
from table_a
where ora_hash(barcode,128) = 105;
and event in ('CLOS','PASG','BUILD');
```

The explain plan provided is this:

```
Plan hash value: 4185630329

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name                           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                                | 35074 |  4212K|   338   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  INLIST ITERATOR                     |                                |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TABLE_A    | 35074 |  4212K|   338   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | TABLE_A_I9 | 14030 |       |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access(("EVENT_TYPE"='BUILD' OR "EVENT_TYPE"='CLOS' OR "EVENT_TYPE"='PASG') AND 
              ORA_HASH("PLACARD_BCD",128)=105)
```

Everything seems correct, but it still is taking a while to provide me with the records.

Comment: How are these columns declared? What do they contain? What are you trying to achieve with this index? This seems to be a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: So how long do you think it should take to return 3-4 million records? Also, please be clear: when you say "return" do you mean elapsed time to retrieve the **first** record or the **4,000,000th** record?

Comment: What is your SQL that is taking 12 minutes?

Comment: is the index being used? what does an explain plan reveal? does your where clause predicate exactly mimic the function call of that index? (*by the way: it really doesn't make sense to ask us about a query and not display that query in the question*)

Comment: I updated above with the query, index, and explain plan.